# Oracle Apex - virtual column not allowed here' while executing a DML command

Tags: oracle-apex

I am currently working in Oracle Application Express 19.1 and I am getting an error that I do not understand .

I created  a interactive grid using the bellow  query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM GG_STAGING_COLUMNS_MAP 
WHERE TO_CHAR(MAP_TABLE_ID)=TO_CHAR(:P20010104_LINK_ID)
ORDER BY COLUMN_ORDER) A;
```

when update value or set new value in column_order using the bellow query

```
     select  MAX(T.COLUMN_ID) from UDBNAT2_TABLES T

    WHERE    T.COLUMN_NAME=:TARGET_COLUMN
    AND T.TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT MAX(M.TARGET_TABLE)
                 FROM GG_MAP_TABLES M
                  WHERE M.ID=:MAP_TABLE_ID 
                  AND T.OWNER=M.TARGET_TABLE_SCHEMA
                  AND T.TABLE_NAME=M.TARGET_TABLE)
   AND T.OWNER  IN      (SELECT MAX(M.TARGET_TABLE_SCHEMA)
                 FROM GG_MAP_TABLES M
                  WHERE M.ID=:MAP_TABLE_ID 
                  )                   ;
```

this ERROR APPEAR

" Error: Process 'MAP COLUMN - Save Interactive Grid Data' raised 'ORA-01733: virtual column not 
   allowed 
   here' while executing a DML command. This error can occur if a column is based on an aggregation or 
   SQL expression. Set column attribute 'Query Only' to Yes to exclude the column from the INSERT and 
   UPDATE statement."

i changed the attribute to query only but the error still appear.

Comment: You said, "when update value or set new value in column_order using the bellow query." But where are you putting that query exactly? Also, have you tried excluding `COLUMN_ORDER` from your `select` clause (explicitly list the columns - don't use `*`)?

Comment: Sorry for that , i forgot to mention that i put this query in default default value, but the error still appear after i change the attribute to query only and add value by manual.

Comment: You said, "but the error still appear after i change the attribute to query only." What attribute are you referring to and are you sure the value is "query only"? What do you mean by "add value by manual?"

Comment: Also, again, have you tried excluding COLUMN_ORDER from your select clause (explicitly list the columns - don't use *)?

Comment: No i don't tried exclude the column_order from query

Comment: Try that as a test.